# Custom TaxonomyTemplate

Tags: custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I have created a custom taxonomy brands and added some brands to various posts.
I also created a file called taxonomy-brands.php and it seems to be working fine. If I visit www.domain.com/brands/adidas then I can see all the adidas branded posts.

However when I visit www.domain.com/brands/ I receive a 404 error. I would like this page to show all the available brands. (adidas, nike, asics etc)

Please help
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a page with slug 'brand'. Then create a custom page template and write required loop to return the terms of the 'brand' taxonomy. Assign that page template to 'Brand' page.

Visit this codex [page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) to know how to code a page template.

And here is an example of how to list terms of custom taxonomy:

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' ); //this will make sure no term is hidden. Even if empty term.

$terms = get_terms( 'my_term', $args ); // replace 'my_term' with your taxonomy.
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_text_domain' ), $term->name ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

Here is the reference for more details about [**get_terms()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Comment: Thanks for this reply, sorry for my delay. This seems to work perfectly however how would I split the taxonomies into an A to Z type of listing?

Comment: You want to filter via alphabet ? Like on that archive page there will be a A to Z bar when user clicks a letter s/he will get items that has that clicked letter at start on the name right?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't automatically generate a template listing terms for a taxonomy. Your best bet would be to create a Page at the url /brands/ and assign it a custom page template. In that template you could write a query to list all your terms for that taxonomy.